# how to count total count in tables from dataset read using linq query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, datatable

below is my query where I am joining few tables using Linq based on some condition

```
var Info = from tblcol1 in Table1
           join tblcol2 in dc.Table2 on tblcol1.EmailID equals tblcol2.EmailID
           join tblcol3 in dc.Table3 on tblcol1.EmailID equals tblcol3.EmailID
           join tblcol4 in dc.Table4 on tblcol3.GroupID equals tblcol4.GroupID
           join tblcol5 in dc.Table5 on tblcol4.RID equals tblcol5.RID
           join tblcol6 in dc.Table6 on tblcol2.RID equals tblcol6.RID
           join tblcol7 in dc.Table7 on tblcol1.EmailID equals tblcol7.EmailID
           where tblcol1.UserId.Equals(gUserID)
           select new Class1()
           {
               EmailID = tblcol1.EmailID.ToString(),
               EmailName = tblcol1.Name.ToString(),
               OpenCount = tblcol7.OpenCount,
               ReadCount = tblcol7.ReadCount,
               TotalCount = tblcol5.RID + tblcol6.RID,
               UnsubscribeCount = tblcol6.IsUnsubscribed + tblcol5.IsUnsubscribed,
           };
List = Info.ToList();
```

where RID are GUID(C#)/Unique Identifier(SQL) and IsUnsubscribed is bit in SQL datatable.

I need to calculate TotalCount and UnsubscribedCount in above query.

```
TotalCount = tblcol5.RID + tblcol6.RID,
UnsubscribeCount = tblcol6.IsUnsubscribed + tblcol5.IsUnsubscribed,
```

How do I do achieve that?

Comment: Are you just looking to `.Sum()` the counts? If so, have you tried `var totalUnsubscribeCount = Info.Sum(_ => _.UnsubscribeCount);`?

Comment: Do you really mean to be adding 2 GUID's on the line TotalCount = tblcol5.RID + tblcol6.RID.

Comment: @DarylBehrens I dont want to add GUID's... I forgot to mention that I want add number of counts for which those GUID's are occurring...

Comment: I need the count of IsUnscribed for each object that I will be creating using select new class1() statement inside the class1 object itself.